# JS - show modal on scroll and prevent it shows again after close

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a modal, that shows after scroll and disappears on top of the page. But, I want it wouldn't shows again if I press the close button on it. (Now, if i close the modal, it shows again over and over and it's very annoying)

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 400) {
        $('#modal-name').css({"display":"block"});
    } else {
        $('#modal-name').fadeOut();
    }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".close-modal, .modal-sandbox").click(function(){
        $(".modal").css({"display":"none"});
    });
});
```

Comment: When you close it, store a value to [localstorage](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/). Then, before showing the modal, check for that value and dont show it if the value exists.

Comment: Just use cookies.

Comment: @SvSv *Do not* use cookies, use `localStorage`. Cookies are sent with every single HTTP request, which is wildly unnecessary. Cookies should be used to preserve state _between the server and the client_ and virtually nothing else I can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a flag `shouldDisplayModal` and persist it to `window.localStorage` like so:

```
var shouldDisplayModal = localStorage.getItem("shouldDisplayModal") == null ? (localStorage.setItem("shouldDisplayModal", true) || localStorage.getItem("shouldDisplayModal")) : localStorage.getItem("shouldDisplayModal");

$(document).scroll(function () {
  if (shouldDisplayModal) {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 400) {
        $('#modal-name').css({"display":"block"});
    } else {
        $('#modal-name').fadeOut();
    }
  }
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".close-modal, .modal-sandbox").click(function(){
        $(".modal").css({"display":"none"});
        localStorage.setItem("shouldDisplayModal", false);
    });
});
```

Comment: And when you reload the window? OP seems to suggest they want persistence.